# Magento 1.7 - 2 stores with differnt domains sharing a cart?

Tags: magento, session-cookies, sessionid

I have successfully setup 2 stores with 2 different domains with Magento 1.7. I am unable to get them to share 1 cart, is there a trick to get this working? I have no been able to find any info on this for current versions of magento.

Thanks,

- Dane

---

EDIT:

Thanks for your replies, one of magento's strengths is the ability to have multiple "stores" while sharing the same admin section, products, customers, ect. (I have this already set up). I just cant get the stores to "share" a cart. In my case I have 2 stores that do not share products, but need to share a cart, so you can add a product to the cart while being in one store then hop over to the other store while having that product still in your cart. gap.com is a good example of this happening with subdomains. I know the functionality is possible because of all the discussions / solutions out there for older versions of Magento. I can just not find a solution for the newer version.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: While I'm sure you have a fairly concrete idea what you mean when you say "share 1 cart" (or "2 stores with 2 different domains" for that matter) it's very unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Alan maybe what he's trying to ask is having two installs share the same DB? *shrug

Comment: One of magentos strengths is the ability to have multiple "stores" while sharing the same admin section, products, customers, ect. (I have this already set up). I just cant get the stores to "share" a cart. In my case I have 2 stores that do not share products, but need to share a cart, so you can add a product to the cart while being in one store then hop over to the other store while having that product still in your cart. gap.com is a good example of this with subdomains. I know the functionality is possible because of all the discussions / solutions out there for older versions of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Magento shopping carts (quotes) are linked to a single store. This is stored by the `store_id` column in the `sales_flat_quote` table of your database. By default you cannot share a shopping cart between stores.

Can you provide a clearer description of how your websites, stores and store views are configured? This information can be found in the admin under 'System > Manage Stores'.